# new line "\n" in yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'd like to do this

```
test: >
  This is a long string
  \n\n\n
  with new lines
```

But it prints out the "\n" instead of making new lines.

I know it's possible to do

```
test: "This is a long string
      \n\n\n
      with new lines"
```

But i'd rather not add quotes everywhere if possible.
Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I'd rather not use empty lines. In other words, i'd like to use \n to show empty lines to make my yml file more readable.

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982706/how-to-break-lines-in-yml-localization-files-on-rails/10983019#10983019

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this

```
test: |+
  This is a long string


  with new lines
```

| after the key helps in beginning of multiline text indented and maintain the indentation for the long string.

Comment: i'd like to use the \n notation instead of using empty lines (just for readability). Is there another way using the \n char?

Comment: then you have to use the qoutes...other solution i don't have any idea

Comment: more you can get here http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#three_trailing_newlines_in_literals

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while asking the same question. I found another solution using the \n in string. When I used `eval(str)` it worked as expected.

Sorry for the use of Python, but I don't code in Ruby. However, I was looking at the documentation and it appears to have the same `eval` function: https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel:eval

Example YAML:

```
text: >
    "This is the 1st row sentence.\n\n\n"
    "This is the 4th row sentence."
```

Example Python:

```
print(eval(yaml_string))

# returns:
# This is the 1st row sentence.
#
#
# This is the 4th row sentence.
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that YAML escape strings the `\n`, so in Ruby you could also parse the text replacing the `\\n` with `\n`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
test: >+
  This is a long string



  with new lines
```

Answer (score -4):

to print a new line in yaml you can do the following code
I am using the degub module msg func like this

```
debug:
   msg:
     - 'hello'
     - 'name'
```